# Dart replace curly braces from string with relative values

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a couple of response from a json which includes curly braces such as ${title} or {title}
How can I replace these vaules with values I preselected?

For example:

```
jsonString = '{title}.2019.mkv'
jsonString2 = '${title}.2019.mkv'
```

How can I replace the field in those Strings with values I preselected like:

```
var title = 'Avengers'
```

Maybe I should just use regex or is there a better way?

Comment: it won't work? or I don't understand the question?

Comment: well I have something like this and it doesnt work: var title json['title']; var url = json['url'] (this is the one with curly braces). and the final url still have braces and I cannot use it

Comment: @AndrewT check my answer

Comment: the question is still confusing, just elaborate it in better way.

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to replace part of the string you can use

```dart
'{title}.2019.mkv'.replaceFirst('{title}', 'Avengers')
```

[Link to documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/String/replaceFirst.html)